# circular shift c

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have to shift the int one place to the right and return it

In Java i can just return n >> 1;

Is this possible in C?

The method we were given is as follows

```
// Return n after a right circular 1-bit shift
unsigned int right_circular_shift_1(unsigned int n) {
```

Comment: Neither in C nor in Java is `>>` a circular shift.

Comment: This solution seems to work. Your homework now is to decipher it: `((n >> 1) | (((n & 1) + (((unsigned int)-1)>>1)) & ~(((unsigned int)-1)>>1)))` xD

Comment: it wasnt homework, it is revision for an exam :D 

i got it to work in the end, thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C does not have a circular shift, so I guess the exercise is to implement it. The way to do this for  a left circular shift is to:

```
- get the current leftmost bit  and save it
- shift the number leftwards by one
- or the saved bit in at the rightmost bit position
```

For  a right circular shift:

```
- get the current rightmost bit  and save it
- shift the number rightwards by one
- or the saved bit in at the leftmost bit position
```

Comment: Except that's the wrong way round. The OP wanted a RIGHT circular shift (if he wanted a circular one at all...), i.e. grab bottom bit, shift right, or in previous bottom bit at top.

Comment: @Julian True - I've modified my answer.

Comment: The remaining tricky part is to get the position of the leftmost bit. I showed a way, but i then saw it's homework and thus deleted my answer :)

Comment: @Johannes I think I would make a small hack and hardcode it for the particular platform I was writing for - particularly for homework :-)

Comment: Btw +1 for the nice manual. I think you would make a great teacher :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you not tried it?

```
n >> 1
```

This will work in C (and other C-based languages) as it does in Java (not circular, though).

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this was downvoted. The OP showed no evidence that they'd tried this before asking whether it were possible; regardless of whether it is circular. Besides they do state,  "I have to shift the int one place to the right and return it"