# circular shifting in c

Tags: c

I'm looking for algorithm that implements a circular shifting to the left of bit binary number
(in c language).
The algorithm will act like >> The right slot will be filled not with zeros but with the numbers moved from left.

and for shifting to the right.

Comment: What is the question here? What have you already tried? Stack Overflow is a website for discussing specific issues relating to programming; it is not a 'free code service'. If that is what you are looking for, then please look elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate the bits in a word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207546/how-to-rotate-the-bits-in-a-word)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943265/circular-shift-c

Answer (score 3):

The idea here is to take the upper n bits (for an n bit shift) and `or` them in to the right of the shifted number.

That should give you a start.

Comment: While that is true, how does one take the top n bits and or them into the right?

Comment: Yes, that is obvious. That still doesn't tell people how to mask the bits and by what to shift, etc.

Comment: @Rudy: you don't need to *mask* anything. The left shift will push zeros from the right.  You use the bitwise `or` operator to add in the topmost (length - n) bits. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: OK, I was thinking too complicated. But is it sure that if you shift a negative int right that it doesn't get sign extended, i.e. does it always shift zero bits in from the right?

Comment: @Rudy: usually, when people deal with bit operations, they're thinking of the number as bit vector, not as a number, signed or otherwise.  Just make sure you're using unsigned integers for these operations and avoid the worry.  That said, if you must use signed numbers, simply create a mask of n ones and `and` that in to the right-shifted upper bits.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NUM_BITS_IN_INT ((sizeof(int) * 8)

int rotleft(int num, int shift)
{
    return (num << shift) | (num >> (NUM_BITS_IN_INT - shift));
}

int rotright(int num, int shift)
{
    return (num >> shift) | (num << (NUM_BITS_IN_INT - shift);
}
```

Comment: why not just `return (n<<1) | (n<0);`

Comment: @Stan: Yes, that is possible, but not as instructive. And I always have my reservations treating a boolean value as a plain integer. Edited my answer accordingly, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
there will be problem with negative number